# Merging two dataframes in python and replace values of two columns in first dataset with data from the second dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for merging two datasets. Two column values of the first dataset will change with two column values from the second dataset

**Dataset 1:**

| Date | Home | Away Home Score | Away Score | Tournament City | Country | Winner | Outcome Decided |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/30/1872 | Scotland England | 0.0 | 0.0 | Friendly | Glasgow Scotland | Draw | Normally |
| 03/08/1873 | England Scotland | 4.0 | 2.0 | Friendly | London England | England | Normally |
| 03/07/1874 | Scotland England | 2.0 | 1.0 | Friendly | Glasgow Scotland | Scotland | Normally |
| 03/06/1875 | England Scotland | 2.0 | 2.0 | Friendly | London England | Draw | Normally |
| 03/04/1876 | Scotland England | 3.0 | 0.0 | Friendly | Glasgow Scotland | Scotland | Normally |

**Dataset 2:**

| Date | Home Team | Away Team | Winner | Outcome Decided |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/22/1967 | India | Taiwan | Taiwan | Penalty Shootouts |
| 11/14/1971 | South Korea | Vietnam | RepublicSouth Korea | Penalty Shootouts |
| 05/17/1972 | Thailand | South Korea | South Korea | Penalty Shootouts |
| 05/19/1972 | Thailand | Cambodia | Thailand | Penalty Shootouts |
| 04/21/1973 | Senegal | Ghana | Ghana | Penalty Shootouts |

As shown I have similar column names in the two datasets. The same entries from the first dataset is available in the second dataset. When it merges it should replace the winner name and outcome decided column values. So merged dataset will have entries as first dataset only the two column values will be changed.

Comment: I believe it is better if you attach the example of merged dataset, it will show us a clearer picture on what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated that the table. First entry of second dataset - winner is Taiwan, there is exactly same row in the first dataset but there it says winner as draw and outcome decided as normally. I want the first dataset to replace the values of draw to Taiwan and outcome decided as penalty shootouts

Comment: What determined that the First Entry of second dataset to replace the First Entry in First Dataset?

Comment: I have solved the problem using a for loop and if else. Thank you so much for your comment @Joshua